# Scroll UITableView frame problems to see UITextField in cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield, frame

In my app, I have a UITableView which has some custom cells and in those I have placed UITextField. That UITextField is sometimes getting blocked my the keyboard which is a issue. So in my situation I am trying to move the whole tableview itself instead of just scrolling to a particular cell which was an issue for me.

Anyway I am having issues this way too.

Anyway this is my code for the textField showing method and ending method. The problem is that the UITableView never moves the right amount. I am just trying to move the UITableview up enough so that the cell that the UITextField that is currently being invoked, is just above the keyboard. **So sometimes it scrolls up too much where I can't see the cell or the whole tableview moves a crazy amount where I do not see it at all.**

Anyway here is my code, does anyone see anything wrong?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)thetextField {
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[[thetextField superview] superview];
    CGRect cellRect = [cell convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view];
    float bottomCell = cellRect.origin.y - cellRect.size.height;
    if (bottomCell >= keyboardY) {
        subtractionAmount = keyboardY - bottomCell;
        didMove = YES;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 
                         animations:^{
                             thetableView.center = CGPointMake(thetableView.center.x, thetableView.center.y + subtractionAmount);
                         }];
    }
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)thetextField {  
    if (didMove) {
        didMove = NO;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 
                         animations:^{
                             thetableView.center = CGPointMake(thetableView.center.x, thetableView.center.y - subtractionAmount);
                         }];
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undesrtood correctly your problem, I encountered that problem one month ago. My scenario was the following: a `UITableView` with `UITextField`s without a `UITableViewController`.

I fixed the problem with the following tutorial: [sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: From the looks of it, I am doing everything from this tutorial but just a bit differently so I am still curious why the code above doesn't completely work.